# How do you ensure that events are applied in order to read model?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, eventstoredb

This is easy for projections that subscribe to all events from the stream, you just keep version of the last event applied on your read model. But what do you do when projection is composite of multiple streams? Do you keep version of each stream that is partaking in the projection. But then what about the gaps, if you are not subscribing to all events? At most you can assert that version is greater than the last one. How do others deal with this?  Do you respond to every event and bump up version(s)?

Answer (score 2):

For the EventStore, I would suggest using the `$all` stream as the default stream for any read-model subscription.

I have used the category stream that essentially produces the snapshot of a given entity type but I stopped doing so since read-models serve a different purpose.

It might be not desirable to use the `$all` stream as it might also get events, which aren't domain events. Integration events could be an example. In this case, adding some attributes either to event contracts or to the metadata might help to create an internal (JS) projection that will create a special *all* stream for domain events, or any event category in that regard, where you can subscribe to. You can also use a negative condition, for example, filter out all system events and those that have the original stream name starting with `Integration`.

Answer (score 1):

As well as processing messages in the correct order, you also have the problem of resuming a projection after it is restarted - how do you ensure you start from the right place when you restart?

The simplest option is to use an event store or message broker that both guarantees order and provides some kind of global stream position field (such as a global event number or an ordered timestamp with a disambiguating component such as MongoDB's Timestamp type). Event stores where you pull the events directly from the store (such as eventstore.org or homegrown ones built on a database) tend to guarantee this. Also, some message brokers like Apache Kafka guarantee ordering (again, this is pull-based). You want at-least-once ordered delivery, ideally.

This approach limits write scalability (reads scale fine, using read replicas) - you can shard your streams across multiple event store instances in various ways, then you have to track the position on a per-shard basis, which adds some complexity.

If you don't have these ordering, delivery and position guarantees, your life is much harder, and it may be hard to make the system completely reliable. You can:

- Hold onto messages for a while after receiving them, before processing them, to allow other ones to arrive
- Have code to detect missing or out-of-order messages. As you mention, this only works if you receive all events with a global sequence number or if you track all stream version numbers, and even then it isn't reliable in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

For each individual stream, you keep things in order by fetching them from a data store that knows the correct order.  A way of thinking of this is that your query the data store, and you get a [Document Message](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/DocumentMessage.html) back.

It may help to review Greg Young's [Polyglot Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv2dKtPq0ME&t=24m54s) talk.

As for synchronization of events in multiple streams; a thing that you need to recognize is that events in different streams are inherently concurrent.

You can get some loose coordination between different streams if you have `happens-before` data encoded into your messages.  "Event B happened in response to Event A, therefore A happened-before B".  That gets you a partial ordering.

If you really do need a total ordering of everything everywhere, then you'll need to be looking into patterns like [Lamport Clocks](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/time-clocks.pdf).